# Trying to obtain first item after XSLT sort in Sitecore

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I have XML that looks like this

```
<xml>
<news>
    <newsitem>
        <publishdate>2011-10-11</publishdate>
        <title>Article 1</title>
        <breakingnewsflag>false</breakingnewsflag>
    </newsitem>
    <newsitem>
        <publishdate>2009-10-14</publishdate>
        <title>Article 2</title>
        <breakingnewsflag>true</breakingnewsflag>
    </newsitem>
    <newsitem>
        <publishdate>2009-10-12</publishdate>
        <title>Article 3</title>
        <breakingnewsflag>true</breakingnewsflag>
    </newsitem>
</news>
</xml>
```

Now what I want to do is obtain the most recent item by date, that has the breakingnewsflag set to true.

It seems I can filter on the flag when doing a for-each

```
<xsl:for-each select="sc:item('/sitecore/content/Home',.)/item[sc:fld('BreakingNewsStory',.)]">
```

and I can sort inside this collection

```
<xsl:sort select="sc:fld('PublishDate',.)" order="ascending" />
```

which leaves me with XSLT that looks like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="sc:item('/sitecore/content/Home',.)/item[sc:fld('BreakingNewsStory',.)]">
<xsl:sort select="sc:fld('PublishDate',.)" order="ascending" />

Article Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /><br />
Title: <sc:text field="title"/> <br />

</xsl:for-each>
```

...but I cannot then obtain the first item.

I can obtain the first item after checking the flag by using this syntax

```
<xsl:for-each select="sc:item('/sitecore/content/Home',.)/item[sc:fld('BreakingNewsStory',.)][1]">
```

...but that will then grab it before the ordering.

I was about to try putting another foreach after the sort clause, to then obtain the first item, but I figured that was going to be needlessly complicated, and there had to be an easier way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you could try using `position()` to get the first item :

```
<xsl:for-each select="sc:item('/sitecore/content/Home',.)/item[sc:fld('BreakingNewsStory',.)]">
<xsl:sort select="sc:fld('PublishDate',.)" order="ascending" />
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    Article Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /><br />
    Title: <sc:text field="title"/> <br />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```